# How can I pass a parameter to the form submit handler in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-hooks, drupal-forms

I am working on a module which is common for a number of forms. I need to pass the $form_id as a parameter to the submit handler and set the form values accordingly in the submit function.

```
function ppi_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

  $form['#submit'][]="action_form_submit";

}

function action_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  //here I need to get the form_id of the form and form_set_value accordingly ... How can I know the form value?
}
```

Is there a way to know the form_id in form_submit ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it as a hidden field in the hook_form_alter(), 
and then use it as you would any other field in the submit handler

Comment: I have discovered that the form_id is already a hidden field in all the fields....